# How to make multiple text views selectable as one?

Tags: android, xml, textview

I have an XML page which produces a list of text views. I have to have them individual, otherwise it wouldn't work. Here they are:

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/name_of_var_code"
        android:typeface="monospace" 
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
    />

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/equals"
        android:typeface="monospace" 
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
    />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/val_of_var_code"
        android:typeface="monospace" 
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
    />
```

Is there any way to make the selectable as a whole group as opposed to individually? Thanks, Ross.

Answer (score 0):

You could put them inside a `LinearLayout` and set a click method and when the user clicks on either one they actualy click on the layout they are in and gives the impression they're are a whole group.